# Is it possible to solve this without trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

My sister had this question in her exam, they didn't study trigonometry yet, and that was the only way I could solve this question, is it possible otherwise? -without using sin,cos, tan-

At two vertices of a rhombus there are 120 degree angles. The diagonal that connects these vertices is 10cm. Calculate the lenght of the other diagonal.

I got 17.2~ with using trigonometry.

Comment: Is the answer exactly equal to $10\sqrt{3}$? Can you find the closed form of your answer - this would help lots in writing my answer!

Comment: Yes it is @TobyMak

Comment: A rhombus is an equilateral parallelogram. This makes pythagoras's theorem powerful... because the diagonals meet at right angles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quickly able to determine that the other two angles are $60$ degree each.
[image: Rhombus] 
Now, this means that if you draw both diagonals, getting four equal triangles, any of those is a right triangle $AOB$ with angles of $30$ and $60$ degrees, that is, half an equilateral triangle. You also know that the short side $OB$ (the one opposite to the $30$ degree angle) measures $5$cm. Being half a side of the equilateral triangle, you also know that the side of the rhombus $AB$ is $10$ cm. Now, from the Pythagorean theorem, you can deduce that the half of the other diagonal $AO$ is $$\sqrt{10^2 - 5^2} = \sqrt{75} = 5\sqrt{3}$$ so the other diagonal is two times that, $10 \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't get the answer without trigonometry, because I drew it the other way around, so the 120 degree was on top, and the 2 60 degrees on the side.

Comment: The argument still works if you rotate the picture by $90$ degrees!

Comment: Ah right... my bad

Answer (score 1):

Well its essentially you have that the diagonal of length $10$ divides the rhombus into two **equilateral triangles**! We have to find the height $h$ of this triangle, and length of other diagonal is then $2h$.

The height of equilateral triangle whose side is $a$ is $h=\frac{a \sqrt 3}{2}$. Here you have $a = 10$, so $h = \frac{10 \sqrt 3}{2}$.

So length of diagonal is $2h = 10 \sqrt 3$

Comment: Ahh, I see thanks a lot for the answer